# Automate login to a website through Gmail using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate login to [Indeed](https://secure.indeed.com/auth?hl=en_US&co=US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&tmpl=desktop&service=my&from=gnav-util-homepage&jsContinue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&empContinue=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.indeed.com%2Fmyaccess&_ga=2.36143904.1242603427.1673200412-1007460264.1673200412) using login option through gmail. However, I am getting this error:

> Couldn't sign you in. This browser or app may not be secure

[image]

[image]

Here is the codebase using **Firefox/Chrome driver**

```
login_url='https://secure.indeed.com/auth?hl=en_US&co=US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&tmpl=desktop&service=my&from=gnav-util-homepage&jsContinue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&empContinue=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.indeed.com%2Fmyaccess&_ga=2.36143904.1242603427.1673200412-1007460264.1673200412'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=caps, service=serv)
# driver = uc.Chrome()
# driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.get(login_url)
time.sleep(4)

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

google = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login-google-button"]')
google.click()
time.sleep(4)

window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)



emailBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@type='email']")
emailBox.send_keys('email@gmail.com')
emailBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(7)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
# passwordBox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='password']")))
passwordBox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@type='password']")

passwordBox.send_keys('password')
passwordBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(7)

driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
```

I found `undetected_chromedriver` solves the issue, however on using `undetected_chromedriver`, it is not able to find the `Continue with Google button` and gives a `NoSuchElementException` error. Here is the codebase for it:

```
login_url='https://secure.indeed.com/auth?hl=en_US&co=US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&tmpl=desktop&service=my&from=gnav-util-homepage&jsContinue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.com%2F&empContinue=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.indeed.com%2Fmyaccess&_ga=2.36143904.1242603427.1673200412-1007460264.1673200412'
driver = uc.Chrome()
# driver.delete_all_cookies()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

test = driver.get(login_url)
time.sleep(4)

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-google-button"]').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No Such Element Exception")
```

I have checked all the answers but none are helping. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: This code is working fine for me, it clicks and opens gmail sign-in pop-up window, just change this line - driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)

Comment: @AbiSaran, it is not opening gmail signin for me in pop-up. Gives `NoSuchElementException` error

Answer (score 0):

Try this to enable private mode in Firefox:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, I get the same error: Couldn't sign you in